# JavaFX - Get the value of a ChoiceBox without Lambdas

Tags: java, javafx

I'm learning Java for 3 weeks now and Im wondering how I do get the value of the chosen item (just Strings) of a ChoiceBox without lambdas by using a Listener. I dont use lambdas because I want to understand whats behind it. I got the following code:

```
public class Main extends Application {     

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);                               
    }

    @Override                                                  
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {     

        //BAUSTEINE:
        ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<String>();          
        choiceBox.getItems().addAll("item1", "item2", "item3");     
        choiceBox.setValue("item1");                                    

        choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener()

        //THIS IS THE PLACE FOR THE LISTENER CODE WHICH I NEED ;)


        //LAYOUT:
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(20,20,20,20));
        vBox.setSpacing(10);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(choiceBox);                   

        //EIGENSCHAFTEN DER SCENE:
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 300, 250);

        //EIGENSCHAFTEN DER STAGE:
        stage.setScene(scene);

        //PROGRAMMSTART:
        stage.show();                                     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these three are identical:

```
  choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>()
  {
     @Override
     public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue)
     {
        System.out.println(observable + oldValue + newValue);
     }
  });

  choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
     System.out.println(observable + oldValue + newValue);
  });

  choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(observable + oldValue + newValue));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Björn! Something which Im asking myself right now is, people which are programming java for some years, do they know for example every method which needs to be implemented because it is abstract in its interface from the java api, also all the syntax of every brackets like that changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue)? or do they just let the IDE fill out a lot?

Comment: When I started Java programming, I mainly used jEdit without most IDE-like plugins, so mainly a text editor. That helped me a lot to get it into my blood. But nowadays I use IntelliJ IDEA, the best Java IDE under the sun. And with that implementing all abstract methods or interface methods is just a keypress away, as same as overwriting methods. And I doubt many developers really start with a text editor. Also nowadays the API is so grown, that it is impossible to have it all in mind exactly.

Comment: hi Björn, I already did from first comment on, but stackoverflow sais: Once you earn 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score...I think thats why you cannot see.

Comment: Nope, voting and accepting are two different tasks. Accepting an answer to your question you can from the start on. And you didn't do, otherwise there would be a green checkmark under the vote score :-)